# Gmapping and TF frames

Tags: slam, navigation, slam-gmapping, gmapping, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and ROS indigo

I published base_link>camera_link frames using static_transform_publisher as follows:

```
<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="link1_broadcaster" args="0 0 0.1 0 0 0 1 base_link camera_link 100" />
```

Then, when I started slam_gmapping it gives the following error:

```
Laser has to be mounted planar! Z-coordinate has to be 1 or -1, but gave: 0.00000
```

This is solved when I change X value to 0 in the transformation as follows:

```
<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="link1_broadcaster" args="1 0 0.1 0 0 0 1 base_link camera_link 100" />
```

But this doesn't reflect my robot's situation correctly.

Also, I noticed in rviz that camera_depth_optical_frame and camera_rgb_optical_frame frames are upside down (as in the picture) and it is also upside down when I change the X value to 0.

Is this normal?

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/208221/gmapping-and-tf-frames/) by [nouf](https://answers.ros.org/users/21560/nouf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2015-04-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If the Z-coord needs to be 1 or negative 1, have you tried setting it to be 1 or negative 1?

Most camera publishers add additional frames (the optical frames) so that the axes align with the camera lens. This means z-axis out the front of the camera, x positive right, and y positive down (the upper-left corner of the screen is 0,0). This is true for depth cameras such as the Kinect, and I'd image that it's the same for your laser scanner.

---

Originally posted by [Adam Allevato](https://answers.ros.org/users/21561/adam-allevato/) with karma: 194 on 2015-05-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0